# When streaming video from on device to another, who is the server and who is the client?

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

I'm writing an Android app where device 1 connects to device 2 through a socket and starts streaming live video to it. In this situation, who is the server and who is the client? 
In my app, device 2 would be listening for a connection. Once it `accepts()`, device 1 streams video to device2.

What I am asking is where does the `ServerSocket` go and where does the regular `Socket` go?

Comment: i should implement live video from one device to another device.i saved video file in sd card and i transfered to another device through socket connection and i received that file in another device.saved in sd card and played successfully but i should implement live video.so what i should do? plz help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServerSocket should go on Device 1 (Server), Device 2 (Client) would consume the video.

Heres an examples:
http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/CreateClientSocket.html

Comment: The problem here is that Device 1 connects to the client to start streaming to it. In connecting, device 2 is the server. In streaming, device 1 is.

Comment: "Almost all ServerSocket objects you create will use their accept() method to connect to a client."

"There are no getInputStream() or getOutputStream() methods for ServerSocket. Instead you use accept() to return a Socket object, and then call its getInputStream() or getOutputStream() methods."

http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week12/29.html
http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week12/30.html